# Include a Javascript function to HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to display an external javascript file to the browser that is included in the HTML file.
I tried the script tag in the head of the html code:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="cardGame.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
```

and nothing was displayed. I thought that this was occuring becuase I have to call specific functions within the html tags so I did this:

```
<div id="computer-choice">
    <label for="computer-choice">Computer choice:</label>
    <ul>
        <p id="demo"></p>
    </ul>
    <button type="button" onclick="getElementById('demo').innerHTML=myCard.toString()">Click Here</button>
</div>
```

And still no result displaying in neither the browser nor the console.

What would be the proper way to include the external javascript file in a way that I just have to include event handlers within tags to add interactivity to the page.

the code in cardGame.js:

```
function Card(rank, suit) {
this.rank = rank;
this.suit = suit;

this.toString = cardToString;
this.createNode = cardCreateNode;
}

function cardToString() {

var rank, suit;

switch (this.rank) {
    case "A":
        rank = "Ace";
        break;
    case "2":
        rank = "Two";
        break;
    case "3":
        rank = "Three";
        break;
    case "4":
        rank = "Four";
        break;
    case "5":
        rank = "Five";
        break;
    case "6":
        rank = "Six";
        break;
    case "7":
        rank = "Seven";
        break;
    case "8":
        rank = "Eight";
        break;
    case "9":
        rank = "Nine";
        break;
    case "10":
        rank = "Ten";
        break;
    case "J":
        rank = "Jack";
        break;
    case "Q":
        rank = "Queen";
        break;
    case "K":
        rank = "King";
        break;
    default:
        rank = null;
        break;
}

switch (this.suit) {
    case "C":
        suit = "Clubs";
        break;
    case "D":
        suit = "Diamonds";
        break;
    case "H":
        suit = "Hearts";
        break;
    case "S":
        suit = "Spades";
        break;
    default:
        suit = null;
        break;
}

if (rank == null || suit == null) {
    return "";  
}
return rank + " of " + suit;
}

var myCard = Card("3", "C");
document.write(myCard.toString());
```

Comment: I can't think of anything that would give you the result you describe other than `myCard` being an object with a `toString` property that was a function that returns a value equivalent to an empty string. So whatever your problem is, it is in the script you didn't share with us.

Comment: What is inside of `cardGame.js`?

Comment: `<label>` elements label *form controls*. You cannot set the `for` attribute to the `id` of `div` in HTML.

Comment: Why is this tagged `jquery` when you don't appear to be using it?

Comment: As a human, I make mistakes. My apologizes.

Answer (score -1):

You are including the files but your inline javascript has wrong syntax.
This is correct:

```
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=myCard.toString()">Click Here</button>.
```

I guess `myCard` is a number or boolean variable type for `toString` method to work but if nothing was shown in console, than it's correct.

Comment: This.  In particular, by omitting `document` above, JavaScript assumes the `window` scope, which does not have a function named `getElementById()`.

Comment: No, it doesn't — not when you are in an onclick attribute of a form control — see [this demo](http://jsbin.com/tuyumajuqa/1/edit?html,output).